# MySQL pivot: Display values in same row

Tags: mysql, pivot

With the below table:

```
CREATE TABLE `STOCK_LEVEL`(
  `ID` int(11),
  `Date` date,
  `ProductCode` varchar(50),
  `Quantity` int(10)
)

INSERT INTO `STOCK_LEVEL` (`ID`, `Date`, `ProductCode`, `Quantity`) VALUES
(1, '2018-02-10', 'PROD01', 15),
(2, '2018-02-10', 'PROD02', 90),
(3, '2018-02-14', 'PROD03', 5),
(4, '2018-02-14', 'PROD01', 11);
```

I would like to see the stock level for a given product on a given day, so I have created a query by product:

```
SELECT 
    Date,
    (Case when ProductCode = 'PROD01' then Quantity else 0 end) As 'AlphaProduct', 
    (Case when ProductCode = 'PROD02' then Quantity else 0 end) As 'BetaProduct', 
    (Case when ProductCode = 'PROD03' then Quantity else 0 end) As 'GammaProduct'

FROM STOCK_LEVEL

WHERE Date IN( '2018-02-10', '2018-02-14')
```

Which will give me a result like this:

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Date       | AlphaProduct | BetaProduct | GammaProduct |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2018-02-10 | 15           | 0           | 0            |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2018-02-10 | 0            | 90          | 0            |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2018-02-14 | 0            | 0           | 5            |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2018-02-14 | 11           | 0           | 0            |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I am probably missing something basic, but is there a way to have this grouped by date like this: (I can't GROUP BY since there is no aggregate?)

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Date       | AlphaProduct | BetaProduct | GammaProduct |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2018-02-10 | 15           | 90          | 0            |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2018-02-14 | 11           | 0           | 5            |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: You need to use `MAX(Case when ProductCode = '[]' then Quantity else 0 end)` AS '[]' and a `GROUP BY date`

Comment: @raymond-nijland that is to say unless you were implying to use a subquery

Comment: That will work @Sirmyself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table without using a subquery

Comment: @RaymondNijland  ... you have comment the right answer  .. post a valid code  so we can rate properly

Comment: @raymond-nijland wow... I actually tried and it didn't work, tried again after your comment and turn's out it worked.

Comment: @scaisEdge i tend not to post answers on duplicated questions.. duplicated question normally get a close vote by me with a duplication link (forgotten this time)

Comment: @RaymondNijland  your comment is the right answer and for duplicated  answer .. is not so easy for new OP find the right answer  .. i think you should post your commen as an answer  and when you have done it i   .. remove my answer ..

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate, I did do my search, I but since the issue is new to me I could not even start to ask the right question :/. Looking at the other question, I don't think I could have answered my question based on that  though, since the trick for me here was the fake aggregation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a a (fake) aggreation function and group by

```
SELECT 
Date,
max(Case when ProductCode = 'PROD01' then Quantity else 0 end) As 'AlphaProduct', 
max(Case when ProductCode = 'PROD02' then Quantity else 0 end) As 'BetaProduct', 
max(Case when ProductCode = 'PROD03' then Quantity else 0 end) As 'GammaProduct'

FROM STOCK_LEVEL

WHERE Date IN( '2018-02-10', '2018-02-14')
group by Date
```

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder : why do people use `CASE` instead of the `IF()` function?

Comment: I prefer case because i more powerfull.  and more easy to understand .. but  in this case is for let the OP more confident with familiar code

Comment: More powerful ok. But for that purpose, isn't it like using a smelting furnace to light a candle? I prefer `IF(ProductCode = 'PROD01', Quantity, 0)` since it is more compact, as fast as using `Case` and easier to read according to me

Comment: In this case  .. the main concept is the use of fake aggregation function and group for reduce rows .. .. the rest is a personal preference .. for me both are good  .. i used  the code of the OP  more is possible so  .. is more easy for the OP to understand and for answering

Comment: granted, I just cringe when I see too complicated code for a purpose. Pretty much like seeing someone rewrite the quick-sort algorithm to sort a 15 elements array.

Comment: Anyway  .. good coded  answer is always good to to see  .. if you thinks so you could post you answer  with your style code  ..   should now have understood how to do and will soon erase this answer

Comment: oh no, your answer is perfect, I was just wondering. If I wrote an answer, the only difference would be that.

Comment: Often the difference between answers  is related  to  style , clarity, completeness .. two good answers are always worth more than a comment

Comment: two time the same answer though : probably not

Comment: Ok  ... as you prefer ..

Comment: @Sirmyself Agreed, 'if'might be cleaner. However, I was looking for a solution first ;). Thank you all!

Comment: @scaisEdge Thank you again for the solution, works perfectly for my case. I would add that instead of MAX one should use SUM since, if there are negative values the MAX will not display them. A marginal situation, but maybe someone might benefit from this. (I did need it for my case)